# slickgrid text selection not working in cells

Tags: javascript, jquery, slickgrid

I've researched this question a bit.  3-4 months ago, the fix to use "enableTextSelectionOnCells" worked, but has broken again.  I'm using v2.1 and implemented the following solutions:

[Text selection in slickgrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20095803/text-selection-in-slickgrid)

[Slickgrid cell text selection does not work properly in Chrome or Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18397036/slickgrid-cell-text-selection-does-not-work-properly-in-chrome-or-firefox)

however, the issue persists.

What happens is, when the code gets to `if (selection.rangeCount > 0) {`, the selection.rangeCount is 0.  When I click and drag the mouse, no highlighting occurs as if I'm actually selecting text.

Is there something else at play here?  Any suggestions to debug further?

I'm using latest chrome and firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out another jquery addon was interfering.

jquery.flot.navigate includes jquery.event.drag.js ~ v1.5, which traps the mousedown event when you try to click to select text.

My fix to minimize impact on the code base was to write a more specific delegate to trap the event first, and call `e.stopPropagation();`